# iOS - UIActivityIndicatorView not stopping

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I am starting UIActivityIndicatorView in a func and want to stop it on success, for some reason it dosent happening:

```
func imageCaller(url: String , success: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.imageLoaderIndicator.startAnimating()

    let handler = AuthenticateHandler()
     self.urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: handler, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    self.imageThumbnailTask = urlSession?.dataTask(with: URL(string:url)!) { data, res, err in

        if err != nil {
            guard let dataResponse = data,
                err == nil else {
                    print("error from dataResponse:\(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")")
                    return

        }

        if let imageData = data {
            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                success(image)
            }
        }
    }
    self.imageThumbnailTask?.resume() 
 }
```

the code above is the network call.

This one is the method calling:

```
func imageThumbnailcall() {
    self.imageCaller( url: self.isShowingThermal ? self.thermalUrl : self.visualUrl, success: { (image) in
            self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.backGroundImageView.image = image
            if self.isInVC {
            self.imageThumbnailcall()
            }
    }) {
        self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
  }
```

Also in the storyboard i checked "hide when stopped"  and also tried wrapping it with  DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Comment: You need to stop it on both success and failure. You need to refactor your code a bit.

Comment: are you sure the call succeeds? If it doesn't you don't have a failure block with which the imageLoader would stop animating.

Comment: @rmaddy i know about the refactoring, yet  it dosnt help even if i put it in the failure.

Comment: @AdamFallon yes i am sure. i debugged it and stoped with a breakpoint on the line... yet is not stopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of branches in your function that doesn't call either the `success` or the `failure` blocks and you also need to stop the activity indicator in the `failure` callback. You should also make sure that you dispatch all UI related activity to the main thread.

```
func imageCaller(url: String , success: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void, failure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.imageLoaderIndicator.startAnimating()

    let handler = AuthenticateHandler()
    self.urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: handler, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    self.imageThumbnailTask = urlSession?.dataTask(with: URL(string:url)!) { data, res, err in

        if err != nil {
            guard let dataResponse = data, err == nil else {
                print("error from dataResponse:\(err?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")")
                failure()
                return
            }
            do{
                //here dataResponse received from a network request
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: [])
                print("erro after parsing data:\(jsonResponse)") //Response result
                failure()
            } catch let parsingError {
                failure()
                print("Error", parsingError)
            }
        } else if let imageData = data, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            success(image)
        } else {
            failure()
        }
    }
    self.imageThumbnailTask?.resume()
}
```

And then call `stopAnimating` from the `failure` block as well:

```
func imageThumbnailcall() {
    self.imageCaller(url: self.isShowingThermal ? self.thermalUrl : self.visualUrl, success: { image in
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.backGroundImageView.image = image
        }
        if self.isInVC {
            self.imageThumbnailcall()
        }
    }, failure: { _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    })
}
```

Not sure what is `isInVC` or how it is set, but you call the same method again based on its value, which might result in an infinite loop of `imageThumbnailcall` calling itself from the success completion handler.

Comment: The isInVC breaks the loop.
as i mentioned i tried your suggestion :   DispatchQueue.main.async{}
and the failure but still it is not stopping

Comment: @ironRoei did you actually look at my code? `DispatchQueue.main.async` is just a tiny part of the changes I made to your code and that's not supposed to solve the immediate problem, that's just supposed to solve the next problem you'd get when modifying UI from a background thread.

Comment: I did modified it according to your code but still no success

Comment: @ironRoei did you use the debugger to step through the code and see which branch your code actually takes? Is `self.backGroundImageView.image` actually set or does that not get executed either?

Comment: Ok , so i modified to your line :
    if let imageData = data, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            success(image)
        } else {
            failure()
        }
and it works.
first of all thanks and second i would like to understand it

Comment: @ironRoei you mean modified it to what? Without knowing what you changed it to I cannot tell for sure why that works.

Comment: i have modified to the line you told me

Comment: @ironRoei you previously said you were using my code, so did you just change that single line in your code to the code from my answer or did you actually use the full code from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
func imageThumbnailcall() {
        self.imageCaller( url: self.isShowingThermal ? self.thermalUrl : self.visualUrl, success: { (image) in
                self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.backGroundImageView.image = image
                if self.isInVC {
                self.imageThumbnailcall()
                }
        }) {
           self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Callback of `URLSession.dataTask` is in background queue so

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
   self.imageLoaderIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

and make sure to handle both success and failure

Comment: tried that as i mentioned DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Comment: you call **self.imageThumbnailcall** recursively might this is the reason here **if self.isInVC {  self.imageThumbnailcall()  }**